# Waves on a metallic rod: force on each element

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, waves, wavefunction, elasticity

Consider a wave impluse $\xi$ on a metallic rod, $\xi(x,t)$ is the displacement of the rod element at $x$ and $t$. In the picture the same elemnte $dx$ is considered before and after the passage of the wave and $F$ represents the force on each section of the element.
[image]

My question: can I assume that

- $\vec{F}(x)$ and $-\vec{F}(x+dx)$ will be always directed in opposite directions (as in picture)?
- If $\vec{F}(x)$ is directed to the left (the component $F(x)$ is negative), then the element $dx$ will be necessarily **streched** ($d\xi>0$)? Or can $dx$ be also compressed ($d\xi<0$), even if $\vec{F}(x)$ is directed as in picture?

---

**Edit:**

more precisely $\vec{F(x)}$ is the force that **the part of the rod on the left of $x$ exerts on the part of the rod on the right of $x$**.

In this way, at $x$ we have $\vec{F}(x)$, while at $x+dx$ there is a force $-\vec{F}(x+dx)$ (since it is exerted by the part of the rod on the right of $x+dx$)

Comment: If $F(x)$ and $F(x + dx)$ have opposite directions, then $F$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added an explanation on the definition of $F$ in this case, so on the right section there is $-F(x+dx)$ acting, which means that $F(x)$ and $F(x+dx)$ will have the same directions.